# How can I make a dynamic repeating alarm in Android?

Tags: java, android, service, alarmmanager

I want to make a repeating alarm but the setRepeating method is limited, I want to create a repeating alarm that repeats but with adjusted timings every day, for example it rings at 4:00 pm one day, then 4:05 pm the next day, 4:10 pm the next and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set your next alarm each time your alarm is triggered.